# Executing stored procedure with results returned by a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How would I go about running a stored procedure with parameters that have values returned by a query?

Here's what I want to do:

```
[dbo].[InsertMultiChoiceList]  [PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID],  [NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID], Answer

// select query returning PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, Answer
```

Select query could return multiple rows.

Comment: There is no way of piping select results into a stored procedure for each row. Sometimes you can replace with a TVF and cross apply but it looks like your proc performs an insert so this isn't possible.

You would need to loop through the results e.g. With a cursor and execute the proc for each row.

Better would be to alter the proc to accept a table valued parameter rather than scalar parameters and alter the proc to deal with multiple rows in a set based way though.

Comment: I think, you can call procedure using loop on result set.